# Source text won't update

Tags: python, django, dictionary, poedit

I have a dictionary in Django and one of the strings that's translated won't get updated in the .po file even though it's changed in the model.

What i've done is to change a badge condition (gamificated site) from:

```
'Wrote %(arg_0)d comments to %(arg_1)d different questions (comments has got at least %(arg_2)d points)'
```

to...

```
'Wrote %(arg_0)d comments to %(arg_1)d different questions'
```

When I open the .po file with Poedit the old condition is still there as source text, even though it's changed in the model. When I change the source text (i.e. removes the last *arg*) in Poedit and save the file the *arg* comes back and the editor complains about the *arg* is missing in the translated text.

What am I doing wrong?

**code from the model (badges.py):**

```
class Commentor_Badge(AbstractBadge):

    badge_name='Commentor'
    description=_('Wrote %(arg_0)d comments to %(arg_1)d different questions')
    #description=_('Wrote %(arg_0)d comments to %(arg_1)d different questions (comments has got at least %(arg_2)d points)')
    trigger_model=get_model("comments","Comment")

    @classmethod
    def listener(cls,instance,**kwargs):
        user=instance.user
        super(Commentor_Badge,cls).listener(user=user,**kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def check_condition_met(cls,params,user):
        num_comments=params[0]
        num_questions=params[1]
        #num_wtfs=params[2]
        question_type=get_model("contenttypes","ContentType").objects.get_for_model(get_model("QAManager","Question"))
        all_comms=get_model("comments","Comment").objects.filter(user=user,content_type=question_type)
        diff_comms=all_comms.values('object_pk').distinct().order_by()
        return all_comms.count()>=num_comments and diff_comms.count()>=num_questions

    @classmethod
    def create_badge_in_db(cls):
        super(Commentor_Badge,cls).create_badge_in_db('Kommenterare',"{'bronze':(5,5,0),'silver':(20,10,0),'gold':(100,50,0),}")
        # super(Commentor_Badge,cls).create_badge_in_db('Kommenterare',"{'bronze':(5,5,2),'silver':(20,10,5),'gold':(100,50,5),}")

    @classmethod
    def get_description(cls,level):
        dic=cls.get_description_args(level)
        return _('Wrote %(arg_0)d comments to %(arg_1)d different questions')%dic
        #return _('Wrote %(arg_0)d comments to %(arg_1)d different questions (comments has got at least %(arg_2)d points)')%dic
```

Comment: have you checked that poedit (i'm assuming you are using poedit) generates the translation file on save? see here for details http://supertuxkart.sourceforge.net/translating_with_poedit

Comment: @LiamSorsby The thing is that it won't save (and therefore generate the .mo file) because of the missing _arg_ in the translation. Even if I remove the _arg_ from the source text and save it comes back.

Comment: Did you run makemessages ? You don't mention it.

Comment: @jpic: Is that really needed when I use Poedit? Poedit converts .po files to .mo files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sync your .po files content with strings from your source code, do this:

```
python manage.py makemessages -a
```

You seem to think that you don't need to do this, because you use Poedit and *"Poedit converts .po files to .mo files"*. Compiling .po files to .mo files is an entirely different process, and a different Django management command - `python manage.py compilemessages`.

First you get strings from your source code to .po files with `makemessages`, then you translate them, and only then you compile them using `compilemessages`.